# Getting latitude and longitude by GPS

Tags: android

I am trying to fetch GPS latitude and longitude on a mobile device. My code below works -- i.e. it provides all the information in the desired manner -- when the device's "use wireless networks" setting is selected, but not when "use GPS satellites" is selected, in which case I don't get any information.

Here's the code:

```
void getLatitudeAndLongitude() {
    boolean gpsEnabled = false;
    LocationManager mLocMan = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Log.e("mLocation#####", "" + mLocMan);

    try {
        gpsEnabled = mLocMan
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    boolean networkEnabled = false;
    try {
        networkEnabled = mLocMan
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    Location mCurrentLocation = null;

    // network*****************

    if (networkEnabled)
        mCurrentLocation = mLocMan
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    // gps********************
    if (gpsEnabled)
        mCurrentLocation = mLocMan
                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    Log.d("current location", "" + mCurrentLocation);
    LocationProvider mGpsProv = null;

    if (mGpsProv == null && mLocMan != null) {
        mGpsProv = mLocMan.getProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    }

    if (mLocMan != null) {

        mylocationlistener mGpsLocListener = new mylocationlistener();
        mLocMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                0 /* minTime ms */, 0 /* minDistance in meters */,
                mGpsLocListener);
        Log.d("Provoider1", "NETWORK_PROVIDER");
    }
    if (mLocMan != null && mGpsProv != null) {

        mylocationlistener mGpsLocListener = new mylocationlistener();
        mLocMan.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                0 /* minTime ms /, 0 / minDistance in meters */, 0,
                mGpsLocListener);
        Log.d("Provoider2", "GPS_PROVIDER");
    }

}

class mylocationlistener implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        if (location != null) {

            latitude = String.valueOf(location.getLatitude());
            longitude = String.valueOf(location.getLongitude());

            Log.e("location==", "" + location);
            Log.e("getLatitude", location.getLatitude() + "");
            Log.e("getLongitude", location.getLongitude() + "");

            if (GlobalConfig.DEBUG)
                Log.d("setUpIndividualWork", "location==" + location);

            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                }
            }, 1000);

            onGPSUpdate(location);

            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(setUpIndividualWorkOut.this,
                    Locale.getDefault());
            List<Address> addresses = null;
            try {
                addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),
                        location.getLongitude(), 1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (addresses != null && addresses.size() > 0) {
                userCurrentLocation = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                Log.e("current location by GPS ", ""
                        + addresses.get(0).getLocality());
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    }
}
```

I will be very thankful for your response.

Comment: Do you have a clear view of the sky when you are trying this? GPS usually doesn't work inside

Comment: Throw in some `else`s: if both 'networkEnabled' and 'gpsEnabled' are 'true', then you are getting that LastKnownLocation twice. Also if both mLocMan and mGpsProv are null, you are requesting those updates twice.

Answer (score 1):

I use it like this:
The class LocationHelper:

```
public class LocationManagerHelper {
private static final String TAG = LocationManagerHelper.class.getSimpleName();
private Context mContext;

private LocationManager mLocationManager;
private GeoUpdateHandler mLocationListener = new GeoUpdateHandler();

public LocationManagerHelper(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
}


public GeoUpdateHandler GetLocationListener() {
    return mLocationListener;
}

public void SetLocationManager(LocationManager locationManager) {
    mLocationManager = locationManager;
}

public LocationManager GetLocationManager() {
    return mLocationManager;
}


public void Stop() {
    if (mLocationManager != null) {
        mLocationManager.removeUpdates(mLocationListener);
    }
}

private class GeoUpdateHandler implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
        String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
        Log.v(TAG, longitude);
        String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
        Log.v(TAG, latitude);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    }
}
```

}

```
//The using:


private LocationManagerHelper mLocationManagerHelper;

 @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            InitializeComponent(getArguments());
            mLocationManagerHelper = new LocationManagerHelper(getActivity());

            try {
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                mLocationManagerHelper.SetLocationManager((LocationManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE));
                mLocationManagerHelper.GetLocationManager().requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 500.0f, mLocationManagerHelper.GetLocationListener());

                String provider = mLocationManagerHelper.GetLocationManager().getBestProvider(criteria, false);
                Location location = mLocationManagerHelper.GetLocationManager().getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                if (location != null) {
                    mLongitude = location.getLongitude();
                    mLatitude = location.getLatitude();
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                Log.e(TAG, "GPS", ex);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this...

```
@Override

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)

{

super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

setContentView(R.layout.main);



LocationManager locationManager =
(LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
MyLocationListener lmh = new MyLocationListener();

String mlocProvider;
Criteria hdCrit = new Criteria();

hdCrit.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);

mlocProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(hdCrit, true);

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 1000, lmh);
Location currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(mlocProvider);

double currentLatitude = currentLocation.getLatitude();
double currentLongitude = currentLocation.getLongitude();
Log.e("lat",""+currentLatitude);
Log.e("lng",""+currentLongitude);
}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

{

public void onLocationChanged(Location loc)

{

loc.getLatitude();

loc.getLongitude();

String Text = "My current location is:" +

"Latitud = "+ loc.getLatitude() +

"Longitud = " + loc.getLongitude();

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

Text,

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}



public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

"Gps Disabled",

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();

}


public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)

{

Toast.makeText( getApplicationContext(),

"Gps Enabled",

Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}



public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)

{

}

}/* End of Class MyLocati
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
package loca.loca;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class LocationActivity extends Activity {

    double x,y;

    Timer timer;
    LocationManager lm;
    boolean gps_enabled = false;
    boolean network_enabled = false;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);


            lm = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);



            gps_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            network_enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);



        if (!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {  Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "nothing is enabled", duration);
            toast.show();

        }




        if (gps_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    locationListenerGps);
        if (network_enabled)
            lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                    locationListenerNetwork);
         timer=new Timer();
         timer.schedule(new GetLastLocation(), 20000);

    }

    LocationListener locationListenerGps = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer.cancel();
            x =location.getLatitude();
            y = location.getLongitude();
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "gps enabled "+x + "\n" + y, duration);
            toast.show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

    LocationListener locationListenerNetwork = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            timer.cancel();
            x = location.getLatitude();
            y = location.getLongitude();
            lm.removeUpdates(this);
            lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);

            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "network enabled"+x + "\n" + y, duration);
            toast.show();
        }

        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        }

        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    };

    class GetLastLocation extends TimerTask {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerGps);
             lm.removeUpdates(locationListenerNetwork);

             Location net_loc=null, gps_loc=null;
             if(gps_enabled)
                 gps_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
             if(network_enabled)
                 net_loc=lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

             //if there are both values use the latest one
             if(gps_loc!=null && net_loc!=null){
                 if(gps_loc.getTime()>net_loc.getTime())
                {x = gps_loc.getLatitude();
                y = gps_loc.getLongitude();
                  Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "gps lastknown "+x + "\n" + y, duration);
                    toast.show();
                }
                 else
                {x = net_loc.getLatitude();
                y = net_loc.getLongitude();
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "network lastknown "+x + "\n" + y, duration);
                toast.show();

                }

             }

             if(gps_loc!=null){
                  {x = gps_loc.getLatitude();
                y = gps_loc.getLongitude();
                  Context context = getApplicationContext();
                    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "gps lastknown "+x + "\n" + y, duration);
                    toast.show();
                  }

             }
             if(net_loc!=null){
                {x = net_loc.getLatitude();
                y = net_loc.getLongitude();
              Context context = getApplicationContext();
              int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
              Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "network lastknown "+x + "\n" + y, duration);
                toast.show();

                }
             }
            Context context = getApplicationContext();
            int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, "no last know avilable", duration);
            toast.show();

}
}}
```